# If I can read my RFID Tags with my Android Phone, doesn't that mean I could emulate my phone to act as the RFID Tag itself?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I am exploring the possibility of being able to use my Android Phone as an RFID Tag itself so I do not have to carry the RFID Tag all the time.

I've research and work about reading the RFID Tag itself with the NFC available in my android phone. In my mind, I should be able to use the same data I read, store it in my phone and somehow be able to project the exact same data back to the RFID reader making my android phone act as the RFID Tag itself.

As I've mention I am able to read the RFID Tag by doing,

```
adapter.enableReaderMode(this@MainActivity, { tag ->
    Log.v("log.log", "I got the Tag!")
    adapter.disableReaderMode(this@MainActivity)
}, flags, bundleOf())
```

I've read on the Card Emulation Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

but it seems that I would need a `AID` to make it work, but that assumes that I know the AID the reader would request.

I can't seems to figure out how to achieve what I am trying to do. Most of the documentation seems to only point to being able to write the same data to a new RFID Tag but that's not really what I want to do.

I am very new to this topic and its highly likely that I just don't understand what things I should be looking or working at. I would really appreciate some guidance whether this is even possible.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So Apparently, this isn't as straight forward as I though it was. For one, the type of NFC/RFID Tag determine whether it could work with Android HCE.

Short Answer: In other words not all NFC/RFID tags could be emulated.